# Javascript imported function not available when pressing back button on browser

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I have the following setup (simplified) which is working fine when the page is loaded:

```
<script type="module" crossorigin>

    import {myfunc} from 'https://mysource.com/main.js';
    window.myfunc = myfunc;

</script>   
<script type="module">

    myfunc();
    
</script>
```

However when the user follows a link and press the browser back button an error says myfunc() cannot be found, so the import has not been performed.

How can I make sure the load occurs each time or preferably is available to the browser via the cache.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't get imported? Might just not be ready at the point your calling it

Comment: Also, this is not how modules are supposed to be used. You need to import, then use it, not make it available on the window. @NickSlash probably has it right, the other module _doesn't necessarily wait_ as it has no need to wait. Maybe add `defer` to the second module?

Comment: Although an over zealous mod has deleted my answer, it is correct. Safari is doing all sorts of buggy behaviour when using modules and pressing the back button. Every issue went away as soon as I altered the header created by PHP session_start();

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask me why but the headers sent by PHP when using the session_start() function causes weird behaviour in Safari with modules.

I fixed the problem by setting `session_cache_limiter()` to `"private"`, it also works if set to `"public"` but does not work if set to "nocache";

```
session_cache_limiter("private");
session_start();
```